# Deprecation Schedule for Google Analytics Content Experiments

Tags: google-analytics

I've noticed recently that Google Analytics Content Experiments are apparently on the path to deprecation, but it's unclear to me what the schedule is for this or when/if this is actually going to happen. Does a deprecation schedule for this feature already exist, or will one exist in the near future? What exactly is planned to be sunset in terms of features and functionality of Content Experiments?

[Deprecation Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OTET.png)